# Can we carry coriander seeds powder and Dried Ginger Powder to Australia?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, australia, food-and-drink

I am from India. I would like to know that Can we carry coriander seeds powder and Dried Ginger Powder to Australia?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**, you can bring them, just declare them for possible inspection.  You will be waved through unless there are visible signs of insect infestation.

However, coriander powder and dried ginger are readily available in Australia, both in regular supermarkets and in specialist Indian grocers.